# Result is [ null ] insted of [ ] after changing from JSON.NET to System.Text.Json in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, system.text.json, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working an ASP.NET Core 6.0 project.

I wrote a query which is related to this property:

```
public List<Holiday> Holidays { get; set; }
```

It returns

```
"holidays": [ null ],
```

This happens after I change from JSON.NET to `System.Text.Json`.

So when using

```
builder.Services
       .AddControllers(options =>
                options.Filters.Add<ApiExceptionFilterAttribute>())
       .AddFluentValidation()
       .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
```

But, when using

```
builder.Services
       .AddControllers(options =>
                options.Filters.Add<ApiExceptionFilterAttribute>())
                    .AddFluentValidation()
       .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

the same code returns

```
holidays : []
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: I think In the List of Holiday List You did not add any data so You got that error . But it is difficult to say because where did you add  data to list .  If you get Json format data you have to add into list

Comment: The only way I can reproduce this is if I initialize the list like this: `Holidays = new List<Holiday> { null }`  (i.e. one item in the list which is `null`).

Comment: Please set a break point in the API method, make sure the Holidays contains values. Then, can you share the API method, so that we can try to reproduce the problem based on your code? I also create a sample and using the System.Text.Json, everything works  well, you could check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kUCw.gif).

Comment: Can you please share [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?